# Вызов метода класса в другом методе этого же класса. Python

Tags: python, классы

Подскажите пожалуйста. Создал класс, хочу вызвать метод в другом методе в этом же классе, но выдает ошибку, как правильно нужно указать?

```
class Converter():       
    def __init__(self, QkVt = 0, P = 0, T1 = 0, T2 = 0):
        self.QkVt = QkVt
        self.P = P
        self.T1 = T1
        self.T2 = T2 
    def ConvRateKgS (self):        
        return round(self.QkVt / (4.19 * (self.T1 - self.T2)), 2)

    def ConvRateTh(self):       
        return round(self.ConvRateKgS (self) * 3.6, 2)
```

Выдает следующую ошибку: *ConvRateKgS() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)*

Читал похожие ответы, но не получается никак.

Спасибо

Comment: `self.ConvRateKgS()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Интерпретатор разворачивает конструкцию self.method() в class.method(self) поэтому не нужно явно указывать в скобках, что вы передаете объект как аргумент, он и так уже передается.